# Как скопировать содержимое формы

Tags: php, javascript, html, form

Привет )

Есть [скрипт](http://platenwood.com/Shablonist/Shablonist.php). Нужно что бы после заполнения была кнопка "Копировать". По ее нажатию должна копироваться заполненная форма. 
Я нашел следующий код в интернете:

function copyText(myText) {window.clipboardData.setData('Text', myText);}

Но даже само по себе, без нужных мне полей оно не работает.

Подскажите:

1) Почему не работает приведенный код (он полностью вставлен в приложенных файлах)?

2) Как изменить его, что бы он копировал заполненную форму?

3) Есть ли прочие ошибки?

[Shablonist.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9dHdfTExNZm9hc2M/edit?usp=sharing)

[patternSelection.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9R2R5MlF2MjRiWkk/edit?usp=sharing)

[mysite.css](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9VVpYdnh2eld5SWs/edit?usp=sharing)

[buttonR.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9bzZjR3hzYXZKM00/edit?usp=sharing)

[1T.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9TVM1Z0NUNXh5UG8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: А как вы его проверяли работает он или нет?

Comment: Да, нажимал копировать - в буфере остается старый текст.

Answer (score 2):

Ваше решение должно работать только в IE. Воспользуйтесь сторонними решениями для кросбраузерной работы

- https://github.com/mojombo/clippy
- https://github.com/valeriansaliou/jquery.clipboard
- https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

Comment: я ему выше уже отправил решение. Для вашего решения нужно устанавливать для одной функции целый модуль, а это простите "геморрой" :)

Comment: а стандартных функций в php и html таких нет???

Answer (score 1):

А почему вы не забираете текст с помощью  jquery :
var text = $('#myForm').html();
или
var text = $('#myForm').text();

?

Comment: я не шарю js, что добавить?

Comment: оформите вопрос в песочнице, только верстка без PHP, я покажу http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mkrichet/gexnp4bo/

Comment: у себя на сайте сделайте так: http://jsfiddle.net/gexnp4bo/1/

Comment: в песочнице нельзя воспользоваться этим объектом

Comment: как правило будет сообщение: Настройка безопасности браузера не позволяет обращаться к буферу обмена :) имейте это ввиду, т.к. во многих браузерах данная функция заблокирована.

Comment: Мне уже начинает казаться что у меня что-то с ПК. Я нажимаю на твою кнопку "Скопировать в буфер обмена" и ничего не копирует ))))))))))))))))))

Comment: на Денвере аналогично ))) только алерт появляется с текстом. Пробовал в мазиле, опере и хроме